# Can one do a *reverse* relational query using parse-server?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, parse-server

I am working on a system where users can block other users.  On the user class, there is a relation called "blockedUsers" which points back to the user table.

If I have a user, and I want to find all the users he has blocked, I do this:

```
ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
ParseRelation<ParseUser> relation = user.getRelation("blockedUsers");
ParseQuery query = relation.getQuery();
List<ParseUser> blockedUsers = query.find();
```

In SQL, this would be something like:

```
select block.blockee
       from block
      where block.blocker = 'SomeObjectId'
```

This would give me the object_ids of all the users who were blocked by user 'SomeObjectId'.

In SQL, I could also reverse this, and say:

```
select block.blocker
  from block
 where block.blockee = 'SomeObjectId'
```

This would give me the object_ids of every user who had blocked user 'SomeObjectId'.

The question is, is there a way to do a query in parse that is similar to the second query?  I have looked at ParseRelation.java, and there is nothing in there which is obvious.  mongodb uses join tables, but I see no way to join **backwards**.

Any help?

Comment: Can we have the sample dataset and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible. Something like this should do what you need:

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> userQuery = ParseUser.getQuery();
userQuery.equalTo('blockedUsers', blockeeUserObject);
List<ParseUser> blockers = query.find();
```